# Regex to check if last character is hyphen (-), if not add it

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to do two things:

1. Remove spaces at the end of a string
2. If a hyphen (-) is not the last character in the string then add it to the end of the string

My attempt, which only replaces hyphens and spaces at the end is:

```
test = test.replace(/-\s*$/, "-");
```

I'm not set on regex just looking for the cleanest way to do this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, working here http://jsfiddle.net/dukZC/:

```
test.replace(/(-?\s*)$/, "-");
```

Comment: `test.replace(/(-?\s*)$/, "-")` is working in the watch window but in my code `test = test.replace(/(-?\s*)$/, "-")` is just setting test to what test was and not adding a hyphen on the end.

Comment: There is no need in parens here.

Answer (score 2):

Make the hyphen optional and it'd work for both the cases:

```
test = test.replace(/-?\s*$/, "-");
                      ^
                      |== Add this
```

Comment: Is it so that for `test   -` it will return `test   -`?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not care about the amount of hyphens in the end then this solution might work well for you:

```
str.replace(/[-\s]*$/, '-');
```

**TESTS:**

```
"test"       --> "test-"
"test-"      --> "test-"
"test-  "    --> "test-"
"test  -"    --> "test-"
"test  -  "  --> "test-"
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for regex. Try:

```
if(yourStr.slice(-1) !== "-"){
    yourStr = yourStr + "-";
} else{
    //code if hyphen is last char of string
}
```

**Note:** replace `yourStr` with the variable with the string you want to use.